# CBV: How To Make A Drop Down Database Query Using Django FormView

Tags: python, django, database

What I would like to do is have a dropdown list containing objects from a database. When the user selects an object, I would like the information displayed on the page.

What I have been able to do is have the values shown in the dropdown list, but I have not been able to display the way I'd like. I've been trying to do so a certain way to hopefully be able to better control the look of the form.

models.py

```py
class Vehicle(models.Model):
    make = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.make + ' ' + self.model


class Package(models.Model):
    make_model = models.ForeignKey(
        Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

views.py

```py
class VehicleCompareView(FormView):
    template_name = "main/somehtml.html"
    form_class = forms.CompareForm
```

forms.py

```py
objectlist = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Package.objects.all() \
    .order_by('make_model__make'))
```

html file

```py
<form method="GET">
     <select class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected disabled>Select Vehicle 1</option>
        {% for q in form.objectlist %}
        <option value="{{q.name}}">{{ q.make_model__make }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
     </select>
</form>

<div>
    <p>Selected Vehicle: {{q.make_model__make}} {{q.make_model__model}}<br>
       Price: ${{q.price}}
    </p>
</div>
```

So let's start with what I have found that somewhat works from messing with the code.

If I use {{form}}, I get the package list, but it only displays the package name of course. If I attempt to use .values() in the query set in forms.py, it returns what I want, but in a dictionary(so it'll literally show 'make': 'someMake', 'model':'someModel', 'package:'somepackage') in the user dropdown list.

When I attempt to do the select/option way that I prefer to, after the for loop doing {{ q }} returns the same list of packages, but if I try to format what I want to see {{ q.make_model__make }} {{ q.make_model__model }} {{q.name}}, nothing shows except a dropdown of blanks(though the correct number of blanks).

There may be a better way than what I'm trying, but from a lot of searching and looking around on here I found my way to using a FormView with a ModelChoiceField query set. At the end of the day, I want a dropdown list to show Make Model Name from the database. When the user makes a selection, I would like to display the attributes on the page. Obviously I haven't even gotten to the issue of the selection part yet. From what I understand I'll need to use Ajax to have everything populate on selection. But that's a problem for another time. For now I'd just like the dropdown to display the way I'd like. Preferably using the select/option method so I can have control over the look rather than just rendering a generic form.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. I started reading all posts on Django query forms I could find, including those that didn't relate to my issue, to better understand exactly how everything works. Someone mentioned that the select statement is built inside the ModelForm. I then realized I was trying to force two different things, and why what I was doing didn't really make sense. I played with the code some more and here is what I did to solve my issue of displaying in the manner I wanted.

forms.py

```py
objectlist = forms.queryset = models.Vehicle.objects.all().order_by('make')
```

html

```py
<form>
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Vehcile 1</option>
            {% for q in form.objectlist %}
                {% for b in q.package_set.all %}
            <option value="">
                {{ q.make }} {{ q.model }} {{ b.name }}
            </option>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </form>
```

Using the nested for loop was the only way I could get the attributes of a related model to display inside the same select dropdown. The model Package has a foreign key called 'make_model' that refers to the model Vehicle. I wasn't able to call 'make_model__make' to display related vehicle names with the package in the dropdown list.

I'll leave my mistake up for anyone else having a similar issue to see what not to do in this situation along with what worked for me in the end.